# How To Joomle Site Convert in to Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

http://famesky.com this is my website which is design in joomla and i want to convert whole site into WordPress. Anyone can help please

Comment: https://besthostingsearch.org/tutorial/how-to-convert-joomla-to-wordpress/

Comment: This question might be better received at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: Please try to look at http://www.wikihow.com/Ask-a-Question-on-Stack-Overflow or other sites for help how to ask questions on stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

As at June 2017, the best free or reasonably priced tool to do this seems to be **"FG Joomla to WordPress"** by Frédéric Gilles.

The free version migrates sections, categories, articles, images and web links but you'll need the paid version to migrate tags, authors, users, menus, custom HTML modules, meta descriptions or meta keywords etc.

The paid version also has a list of add-ons where you can continue to run some Joomla extensions e.g K2, VirtueMart, Zoo, Kunena, Community Builder, JEvents and various other extensions for an additional fee. Alternatively, you'll need to find equivalent add-ons in WordPress.

You'll also need to find an equivalent template.

There are other commercial tools available but I haven't had much success with them (although it has been a while since I used a Joomla to WordPress migration tool).